# Adding Column From One Dataframe To Another Having Different Column Names Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, names

I have a dataframe called **prices** contains two columns : Timestamp and closing prices. The contents are as below :

```
Timestamp        Close
1/1/2017 0:00   966.6
1/1/2017 1:00   963.87
1/1/2017 2:00   963.97
1/1/2017 3:00   962.83
```

I have another dataframe called **output** the contents of which are as below :

```
created_at        count
6/7/2018 19:00      1
6/7/2018 20:00      2
6/7/2018 21:00      3
6/7/2018 22:00      2
6/7/2018 23:00      1
```

What i want to do is to append the closing price from the **price dataframe** to the above **output dataframe** to get a dataframe that should look like this :

```
created_at        count       close
1/1/2017 0:00     5           966.6
1/1/2017 1:00     1           963.87
1/1/2017 2:00     1           963.97
1/1/2017 3:00     1           962.83
```

I know I can merge the 2 dataframes and then drop the Timestamp column using

```
output.drop['Timestamp'], axis=1)
```

and I can remove the NaN values using\

```
output.dropna()
```

but I cannot merge the 2 files on different columns. How can I do this? The updated code is as below :

```
import pandas as pd

path1 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Bullcrap Testing Delete Later\Bitcoin Prices Hourly Based.csv'
path2 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Bullcrap Testing Delete Later\adam3us.csv'
path3 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Bullcrap Testing Delete Later\ascending and final.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(path2)
df3 = pd.read_csv(path3)

output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="created_at") #column_name should be common in both dataframe. how represents type of intersection. In your case it will be inner(INNER JOIN)

df4 = output.created_at.value_counts().rename_axis('created_at').reset_index(name='adam3us_tweets')

df4 = df4.sort_values(by=['created_at'])


# output the dataframe df4
print(df4,'\n\n')


df4.to_csv('results.csv', encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `pd.merge` has the `left_on` and `right_on` parameters where you can define differently named columns. Start with documentation when you have questions: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: You can also rename the column before merging, so that you don't wind up with both key columns after the merge.

Comment: @A.Kot whenever i use the left_on and right_on i get  **ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)**

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory: you can't select 2 columns on the left df and merge on 3 columns on the right df. What is your right_on and left_on equal to?

Comment: @A.Kot it worked. Dunno what happened but on the 8th execution it just started working