# Populating new column in dataframe from existing two with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

How would I go about adding a new column to an existing dataframe by comparing it to another that is shorter in length and has a different index.

For example, if I have:

```
df1 =   country   code  year
      0 Armenia    a    2016
      1 Brazil     b    2017
      2 Turkey     c    2016
      3 Armenia    d    2017

df2 =  geoCountry   2016_gdp  2017_gdp
     0 Armenia        10.499    10.74
     1 Brazil         1,798.62  2,140.94
     2 Turkey         857.429   793.698
```

and I want to end up with:

```
df1 =  country   code  year  gdp
     0 Armenia    a    2016  10.499
     1 Brazil     b    2017  2,140.94
     2 Turkey     c    2016  857.429    
     3 Armenia    d    2017  10.74
```

How would I go about this? I attempted to use answers outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803535/adding-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-having-different-column-names-using) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error) to no avail. I also did the following which takes too long on a 90000 row dataframe

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
if row['country'] in list(df2.geoCountry):
    if row['year'] == 2016:
        df1['gdp'].append(df2[df2.geoCountry == str(row['country'])]['2016'])
    else:
        df1['gdp'].append(df2[df2.geoCountry == str(row['country'])]['2017'])
```

Comment: Let me know if my response was any helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars = 'geoCountry', value_vars = ['2016_gdp', '2017_gdp'], var_name = ['year'])
df1['year'] = df1['year'].astype('int')
df2['year'] = df2['year'].str.slice(0,4).astype('int')
df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['country','year'], right_on = ['geoCountry','year'])[['country', 'code', 'year', 'value']]
```

Output:

```
   country code  year     value
0  Armenia    a  2016    10.499
1   Brazil    b  2017  2,140.94
2   Turkey    c  2016   857.429
3  Armenia    d  2017     10.74
```

Answer (score 0):

You mainly need the **melt** function:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split("_").str.get(0)
df2 = df2.rename(index=str, columns={"geoCountry": "country"})
df3 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['geoCountry'], value_vars=['2016','2017'],
    var_name='year', value_name='gdp')
```

After this you simply merge the df1 with the above df3

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df3, on=['country','year'])
```

Output:

```
pd.merge(df1, df3, on=['country','year'])
Out[36]: 
   country code  year       gdp
0  Armenia    a  2016    10.499
1   Brazil    b  2017  2140.940
2   Turkey    c  2016   857.429
3  Armenia    d  2017    10.740
```